# Consolidating many try/excepts that have different try bodies but identical behavior when an exception occurs?

Tags: python, try-catch

I currently have code that contains many `try`/`except` blocks with identical logic in the `except` suite, but differing logic in the `try` suite, like so:

```
try:
    x = var_1 + var_2
except TypeError:
    x = None
...
try:
    y = (var_3 + var_4) / var_5
except TypeError:
    y = None
```

Notice, I'm also *always* catching a `TypeError`.

Is there a cleaner way of writing such logic?

One idea I had would be to wrap each of the variable assignments in a lambda expression, and pass the lambda into another function that contains the `try`/`except` block like so:

```
def calculate(lambda_func):
    try:
        return lambda_func()
    except TypeError:
        return None

x = calculate(lambda: var_1 + var_2)
```

However, it seems like this attempt is misusing lambda expressions. The idea I'm trying is to wrap the logic on the right side of the assignment in a code block that I can execute.

Is there any other way to do what I'm trying here? Or is the only way to wrap each assignment in its own `try`/`except`?

Comment: What is the lam_1 parameter of your lambda? Is that the reason for the TypeError?

Comment: @quamrana Oops, fixed the lambda. It wouldn't take any parameters. The reason for `TypeError` would be if one or more of the variables, `var_1` or `var_2`,  are `None`

Comment: No, I was asking whether the reason it returned None was because when trying to execute the lambda there was a missing parameter and could that raise a TypeError?

Comment: Oh, yes. That is why my (incorrectly written) lambda was causing the `TypeError`. The new lambda approach works. I'm just not sure if this is the correct use of lambdas at this point. Is this approach ok, or is there another way I should go about this?

Comment: It’s more of a style thing. (I would certainly try your approach of eliminating the duplicate try/excepts)

Comment: The lambda approach works perfectly. I suppose at this point, my only concerns are if this would be a proper use of lambdas and if this would be considered "good" styling. It definitely beats having a ton of `try`/`except`s though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def core_func(x:int, y:int):
    return x+y

def calculate(func,x,y):
    try:
        return func(x,y)
    except TypeError:
        return None

x = calculate(core_func)
```

Maybe I can write functions like above, but I think you can make function simpler.

```
def calculate(x,y):
    try:
        return x+y
    except TypeError:
        return None

x = calculate(x,y)
```

Comment: Ah, one correction was added. The variable assignments don't necessarily have the same number of operands. I think this approach would still work if I used variadic parameters though.

Comment: If so, Please use list as parameter. If this is not correct, let me know please with comment. If my answer is correct, please click .... :)

Comment: A list won't really work, as the operators can differ as well.

Comment: I want to help you, but maybe seems I did not understand your work. I don't know well this url can help you. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/     Good luck!